# jQuery: html() not available in event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Newbie question:

I have a web page with a single p element. I thought I could access the p.html() inside an event, but can't. Is there a way to access the element inside the event as a jQuery element?

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>      
    $(function () {
        $("p").first().bind('click',null, function (event) {
            this.innerHTML = "this works";
            this.html('this does not');
        });
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` in handler function is your DOM element.. it doesn't have `.html` function.. wrap it with `$` to make it a jQuery object and do a `.html`

```
$(this).html('this does work now');
```

**Full code:**

```
$(function () {
    $("p").first().bind('click',null, function (event) {
       this.innerHTML = "this works";
       $(this).html('this does work now');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

When using `this` in your context, it's the DOM element. You can use native methods, like `innerHTML`. `html` is a jQuery method, which would require you use `$(this).html()`.

---

**References:**

- `$().html()` - https://api.jquery.com/html/
- `element.innerHTML` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

As you  are using `this`, it is a `DOM` object and 'html' is method of `jQuery` object.

You need to convert it to `jQuery object` before using any `jQuery api`. To convert it simply use $(`DOM Object`) construct.

Now this will work -

```
$(function () {
    $("p").first().bind('click',null, function (event) {
        this.innerHTML = "this works";
        $(this).html('this works !!!)');
    });
}
);
```

According to [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) -

`$()` — searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that references these elements:

```
$('div.foo');
```

Here `div.foo` is DOM element which is `this` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code: this is not a jQuery object.

```
    $(function () {
        $("p").first().bind('click',null, function (event) {
            this.innerHTML = "this works";
            $(this).html('this will work now');
        });
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is DOM element ,it is not jquery object .so use `$(this)`

```
  $(this).html('this now works');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (nned jQuery object):

```
$( this ).html()
```